# Regular expression to test exact word with a trailing dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having a dynamic variable which I need to match against a source.

```
Source: 'text clientLogin padding float';
search: '.clientLog'
```

The search text has a leading dot('.') which should be omitted while comparing.

For the above example I should:

1. Get the part of search after '.'(dot)
2. Check the source for the search text i.e `clientLog` & return true if whole word matches.(in this example it should return false as source has  `clientLogin`).

I am trying to use RegEx to achieve this

```
var regEx = new RegExp(k); // k is the search text
 if(regEx.test(classNames)){....
```

Above code is inside jQuery.each,k is the key of the object which is being iterated.I did not figure out how to omit the '.' but read somewhere to implement **Word Boundries** for the exact match.

Please suggest.

thanks

Comment: You probably want `var regEx = new RegExp('\\b' + k.substring(1) + '\\b')`.

Comment: I guess there are only dots in the beginning, right? And inside `search`, there cannot be any other non-word chars, except for `-` maybe. And the character at the end is also a word char, right?

Comment: The other option (without using regular expressions) is `classNames.split(' ').indexOf(k.substring(1)) !== -1`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes search will have a leading dot all the time & only alphabets afterwards

Comment: @Phylogenesis can we not omit by using some RegEx rule? I do not want to get a substring.

Comment: Yes, you can indeed use dynamite to dig a hole in your garden.

Comment: What's the motivation to not use `substring` when you'd have to modify the search string anyway?

Comment: Im sorry I thought this to be more efficient using RegEx.. wont it be?

Comment: No, setting up and executing a regular expression is a heck of a lot more complex than a simple `String#substring` call.

Comment: so we should use RegEx for complex patterns only or what?I did not use the sustring way because I thought this could be achieved in single line using RegEx

Comment: @techie_28: The `.` is not a word symbol. `\b` before `.` denotes a trailing word boundary, meaning that the character before the `.` must be a word character (digit, letter or underscore). You *may* try using `'(?:^|\\W)' + search + '\\b'` (`var regEx = new RegExp('(?:^|\\W)' + k + '\\b');`), and that will match either a start of string or non-word char before `.` and it will mean the same if the `k` starts with any word char. Is that working well for you? However, this means the `.` dot will still be part of the search pattern. If `classNames` do not contain dots, then this is impossible.

Comment: Another similar approach - `var regEx = new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)' + k + '\\b');`

Comment: as per discussions I think best way of doing this is as suggested by @Phylogenesis.. if you please post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var
source = 'text clientLogin padding float',
search = '.clientLog',
pattern = '\\b'+search.replace(/^\./, '')+'\\b',
result = new RegExp(pattern).test(source);
```

Notes:

- We strip off the leading '.' from the search string while building the pattern
- We use word boundary markers (`\b`). This helps ensure that "login" is not considered a valid match for "log", for example, like in your case.
- The double-escaping (`\\b`) is necessary as we're building our pattern as a string - this is necessary for dynamic patterns fed to the `RegExp` constructor.

Comment: How about omitting the '.' using RegEx rule instead of finding substring?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I meant if we can write a RegEx rule which can disregard the dot while matching. As per other people comment I think best way to do this would be just getting the substring and finding its index in the source.

Answer (score 2):

### Stripping text

In JavaScript, you can strip text with the `substring()` method like this:

```
var str = "Hello World!";
var sub_str = str.substring(1, str.length);
```

In `substring(x, y)`, x is the starting index of the new string, y is the ending index. The indecies in JavaScript start at 0, so we have to use the next index to omit the first character in the string.

You can also read it up [here on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp).

---

### Regular Expressions

You can search RegEx patterns in strings like this:

```
var str = "Hello World!";
var pos = str.search(/World/); // Attention: No quotes here!
```

`pos` equals the index of the first match of the given expression. If your expression did not match your string, then `pos` will equal `-1`.

Note, that `str.search(/World/);` is basicly the same as `str.search(new RegExp("World"));`

You can also read it up [here on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp).

---

To check, if your string contains that classname, you could do this:

```
var str = "classname1 classname2 classname3";
var search_str = ".classname2";
if(str.search(new RegExp("\\b(" + search_str.substring(1, search_str.length) + ")\\b")) > -1){
// classname found
} else {
//classname not found
}
```

Comment: This fails the example given in the question. It does not do whole word matching.

Comment: @Phylogenesis I edited the regular expression, so it does whole word matching with the `\b` flag now. Inbefore, even `notclassname28`would be matched, this is not the case anymore. Thank you for pointing that mistake of mine out. :)